# Expresión regular o función para validar un texto en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Necesito validar campos de texto de un formulario con jQuery, en los cuales se permitan letras, ya sea en mayúscula o minúscula, letras con acentos, los signos de puntuación y los caracteres que se suelen usar en una redacción. Pero que en cambio no deje entrar carácteres como podría ser **`#`**, **`{`**,   **`^`**, etc. ... Lo que vendrían a ser caracteres que no se utilizan para escribir, al menos en una situación normal. 
Gracias

P.D.: La pregunta deja la respuesta muy abierta, pero no voy a poner todos los caracteres... Busco sólo una aproximación a mi definición en el caso que alguien lo tenga ya hecho y pueda servirme.

Answer (score 4):

Utilizaría algo de este tipo:

```
^[0-9A-Za-zñáéíóúÑÁÉÍÓÚüÜ;\.:'\s\-]+$
```

- Lo que está entre `[` y `]` es una lista de letras o signos capturados por la regex (expresión regular).
- El `^` al principio quiere decir que no puede haber nada mas antes del `^`.
- El `$` al final quiere decir que no puede haber nada mas despuel del `$`.
- El + quiere decir que la letra anterior (en este caso es la lista de letras) tiene que ocurrir por lo menos una vez o mas veces.

Otros ejemplos:

- `^a$` – la regex captura/acepta el texto, solo si hay una `a`, nada antes y nada después
- `a\+` – el texto tiene que tener por lo menos una `a` o mas para ser capturada por la regex
- `[abc]` – las letras `a`, `b` y `c` son aceptadas/capturadas por la regex

Sería cuestión de añadir los signos de puntuación que consideres comunes en una redacción.

Por ejemplo para añadir el `,` lo pones en la lista de arriba:

```
^[0-9A-Za-zñáéíóúÑÁÉÍÓÚüÜ;\.:'\s\-,]+$
```

Quidado con letras o signos especiales como paréntesis. Estas las tienes que *esconder* con un `\` (dependiendo del dialecto de regex que estés usando — por ejemplo en Javascript sí lo tienes que esconder).

Lee mas sobre regex aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: ¿Para añadir una "," por ejemplo? o un paréntesis? Es que no termino de entender muy bien donde poner segun que caràcteres