# Como puedo validar con jquery si un campo solo tiene letras

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo validar un campo que solo tenga letras pero con jquery?
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Expresión regular o función para validar un texto en jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6143/expresi%c3%b3n-regular-o-funci%c3%b3n-para-validar-un-texto-en-jquery)

Comment: En jQuery ahí una función que se llama isNaN y fácil de válida no existe algo así pero para letras?

Comment: Tristemente no. Tienes que hacer tu propia función para ello. Ahora que leo bien, tu pregunta no se parece en nada a la que acabo de marcar como duplicado por eso la acabo de retirar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se hace con expresiones regulares, esta acepta letras y espacios:

```js
function accionarLaCosaEsta(texto){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '¿Son letras y espacios solamente? ' +  sonLetrasSolamente(texto);
}


function sonLetrasSolamente(texto){
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
  return regex.test(texto);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="texto" onkeyup="accionarLaCosaEsta(this.value)"/>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Aquí agrego un ejemplo con JQuery

```js
jQuery('#texto').on('keyup', function() {
  jQuery('#demo').html('¿Son letras y espacios solamente? ' + sonLetrasSolamente(this.value));
});

function sonLetrasSolamente(texto) {
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
  return regex.test(texto);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Con JQuery:<br />
<input type="text" id="texto" />
<div id="demo"></div>
```